# SSRS Report Builder (3.0) keeps freezing when previewing a report

Tags: ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

Whenever I click on the Preview button while my cursor is in a field in the Properties pane, Report Builder freezes completely causing me to have to kill Report Builder (losing my changes along the way).  I've uninstalled and re-installed Report Builder with no change to this behavior.  Has anyone else encountered this and if so, have you found a solution to the issue?

Answer (score -1):

save your data. and upload a copy to test folder in dev, qa, or worse case prod (make it a hidden folder in prod). apply correct connection strings and test. If you have VS i would have suggested to make sure to delete from bin folder your .data file esp after you make changes to rdl.

Comment: None of that solves the problem, it just provides an unacceptable work-around that's no better than the actual problem.